# Python Lists and tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

What is difference between

```
[439 301 481 194 208 415 147 502 333  86 544 353 229]
```

And

```
[439, 301, 481, 194, 208, 415, 147, 502, 333,  86, 544, 353, 229]
```

When I try

```
sent = sent[np.newaxis,:]
```

On the 2nd array it gives me the following error:

```
File "Mymain.py", line 200, in <module>
    sent = sent[np.newaxis,:]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: `[` ... `]` does not automatically give you a `numpy` array.  `numpy` is a ***third-party*** add-on for handling arrays in the way to which you are (evidently) accustomed in Matlab.   `[` ... `]` on its own gives you a basic Python `list`, which does fewer tricks.   Convert your `list` into a numpy array with `numpy.array( [` ... `])`

Comment: This clearly lacks of a context. You can define a list by writing `[1, 2, 3]`, but `[1 2 3]` is not a valid syntax. Where did that first line come from?

Comment: I love python because the errors are so readable (not just the programs!). So your error says list (`sent`) indices(`np.newaxis,:`) must be integers or slices and not tuple( `np.newaxis,`).Remove `,` in `sent = sent[np.newaxis,:]`. It should be working fine assuming you've done everything else the right way (like figuring out the difference between np.array and python list etc..).

Comment: The lack of commas suggests that the first line is the print of a numpy array.  The second is probably a list.  Indexing that works on an array often doesn't work on a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you are trying to send a array that is a python list. At first you need to convert it into nampy array.

```
import numpy as np 

py_list = [439, 301, 481, 194, 208, 415, 147, 502, 333,  86, 544, 353, 229]
convert_numpy = np.array(py_list )
sent = sent[np.convert_numpy,:]
```

and for 1st line `[439 301 481 194 208 415 147 502 333  86 544 353 229]` you need to add comma to separate the value.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's a numpy array and a python list.

Try:

```
import numpy as np 
a = [1,2,3]
b = np.array(a)
print(a,b)
```

You can find more information here 
http://www.numpy.org/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, `sent[np.newaxis, :]` is a numpy array syntax.

Therefore, you're expecting `sent` to be a `numpy.array`, but it is not.
As stated by the error: `list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`, `sent` is a list. Since `np.newaxis, :` is a tuple, Python gives you this error.

You need to define `sent` as an array.
For this purpose, you can convert it from a list to an array:

```
sent = np.array(sent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `type` to chech what is what:

```
a=[439, 301, 481, 194, 208, 415, 147, 502, 333,  86, 544, 353, 229]
type(a)
```

the results is:

```
<type 'list'>
```

Convert your list to np.array using:

```
import numpy as np
sent = np.array(sent)
```

And the error will go away.